# How to detect if view has finished re-drawing

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an ImageView and I want to change it's size in runtime. So I do the following:

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) imgView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = size;
params.height = size
imgView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The problem is that based on these new width and height I want to change my another ImageView, but seems like LayoutParams are not applied immedately, because Log put just after setLayoutParams prints old width value. So here is a question: is there any way to force ImageView to update (I already tried `View.invalidate()` and `View.requestLayout` but no success), or is there any way to detect if ImageView has finished updating, so I can use it's new parameters?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086859/setlayoutparams-doesnt-work-second-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attach a `viewTreeObserver`. Which will get called every time layout is changed

You can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733813/how-can-you-tell-when-a-layout-has-been-drawn)